# What is the best way to process the content of sysfs using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

The Linux kernel exposes information about the current environment using the sysfs filesystem in /sys. I'm interested in getting information about online CPUs and their memory hierarchy (Level 1 to Level 3 caches).

Since all this information is basically text files I could write a parser on my own, but I'm curious what the best way of processing the information in sysfs is. Currently I found two alternatives:

`libsysfs`

and

`libudev`

The downside of `libsysfs` seems to be that the code is now almost 5 years old and almost no documentation is available, `libudev` seems more active but documentation is quite rare. There was only one useful tutorial I found on `libudev` -- http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

What is the state of the art way to process content from sysfs in C/C++?

**[Update]**

Currently it is not possible to access data stored in `/sys/devices/system` due to the fact that the exposed information are not real devices. The only way to access this data is to do it manually.

Comment: Since you tagged this with `unix-programming`, is `awk` a possibility? That seems like the path of least resistance when it comes to text parsing.

Comment: A while ago I was looking for something for this as well, and in the end gave in and wrote my own, as I realized that in all the files, I was really only interested in a specific bit of information, so the overhead was not worth it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The kernel authors have published [sysfs-rules.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt), which explains how sysfs must be used. They point out in particular

> Do not use libsysfs

Comment: Following the above description I worked with `libudev` unfortunately it does not list devices / subsystems in `/sys/devices/system` is there a special reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

wearing your shoes I'd probably write my own lib. Since those libs may not ( and probably will not ) meet all of your requirements. fstream ftw.